# How to include descriptive statistics table beneath a ggplot with fill variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to create a plot with summary statistics for each variable beneath a ggplot in the style of `ggsummarystats()` (https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggsummarystats.html).

[image: ggsummarystats table]

I'd like it to include mininum, first quantile, median, third quantile, maximum, sample size, mean, standard deviation, and standard error.

```
head(ToothGrowth)

ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)


(toothgrowth_summaries <- ddply(ToothGrowth, c("supp", "dose"), summarise,
                          min = min(len),
                          q1 = quantile(len, 0.25),
                          median = median(len),
                          q3 = quantile(len, 0.75),
                          max = max(len),
                          N    = length(len),
                          mean = mean(len),
                          sd = sd(len),
                          se = sd/sqrt(N)
))

ggplot(toothgrowth_summaries, 
       aes(x = dose, 
           y = mean, 
           fill = as.factor(supp))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           color = "black", 
           position = position_dodge()) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-se, 
                    ymax = mean+se), 
                width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9))
```

[image: The plot the code above generates]

I want to generate the plot above but with a summary statistics table for each bar in the bar graph - i.e. OJ at dose 0.5, OJ at dose 1.0, and OJ at dose 2.0, separate from VC at dose 0.5, 1.0, and 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same `ggsummarystats()`: only the grouping needs to be included in the code:

```r
# some comment
library(ggpubr)


ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)

ggsummarystats(
  ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", color = "supp",
  ggfunc = ggbarplot, add = "median_iqr",
  fill = "supp",
  ylab = "mean", ## Change axis title
  legend = "top", ## Set legend on top, bottom, or sides of the plot
  position = position_dodge(width = 0.7), ## Adjust space between groups
  palette = "npg"
)
```